# Winstonjs: Is it possible to have custom formatters for different transports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I want to have different formats for console and file transport in Winston because I want to colorize console logs on my own using chalk module.
I created logger using the following code:

```
this.logger = createLogger({
    levels: {
        fatal: 0,
        error: 1,
        warning: 2,
        info: 3,
        debug: 4,
        trace: 5,
    },
    format: format.simple(),
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            json: false,
            level: 'trace',
            formatter: (options) => {
                console.log(options);
                return "formatter";
            },
        }),
        new transports.File({
            filename: 'combined.log',
            json: false,
            level: 'trace',
            formatter: function(options) {
                console.log(options);
                return "formatter";
            }
        }),
    ]
});
```

But `formatter` functions are never called, I just see the default JSON output both in console and file.
Is it even possible to separate formatters for different transports?
I'm using **Winston 3.0.0-rc5**.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. The core of my example is based on their api page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston .

```js
const winston = require('winston');

var config = winston.config;
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      formatter: function(options) {
        console.log(options);
        return "console!";
     }
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ 
        json: false, //THIS is important for type "File"
       filename: 'test.log',
       formatter: function(options) {
        console.log(options); 
        return "log file!"; 
       }
    })
  ]
});
logger.info('nono');
```

Comment: It seems that you installed previous version, Winston 2. I'm on "3" branch, seems that I should create an issue on their Github page.